# Object reference not set to an instance of an object while starting Samsung Kies

Tags: android

I've installed the above mentioned samsung kies on my system. After installing, when I try to run it, I'm getting the following error:

Fatal Error alert box which shows "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Does anyone know how to fix this?

- OS: Windows 7 32 Bit
- Kies version: 2.5.0.12094_28_8